# fill down in excel, dont increment certain terms

Tags: excel

Cell B4 and B5 are fixed. B4 is a radius, B5 is PI()/180, Formula is =B4*SIN(B5*A7), column A is 0 to 360, I want to filldown from top to bottom and increment col A term, but not the col B terms

Comment: Then lock them with `$`: `=B$4*SIN(B$5*A7)`.

Comment: Thanks a Bunch Big Ben!

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering here so you can mark this question as solved.

As @BigBen said, you can lock a row or column by placing `$` in front of the row number or column letter. So if you write your results in column C, your formula for cell C1 should be:

`= B$4 * SIN(B$5*A1)` or `= $B$4 * SIN($B$5*A1)` (the second formula also locks the B column for safety)